# boost filtering_istream gzip_decompressor uncompressed file size

Tags: c++, boost, gzip

I am using the boost filtering stream object to read gzipped files.  Works great!
I would like to display a progress bar for the amount of the file that has been processed.  I need find the input uncompressed file size.  Does the gzip decompressor have access to the original file size from the gzipped file?  I couldn't find it on the [boost gzip_decompressor reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/gzip.html#basic_gzip_decompressor) page.  Really the progress dialog is the goal, is there another way to figure out position in the compressed file?

```
    // gets compressed file size, need uncompressed size
    boost::uintmax_t fs = boost::filesystem::file_size (
        boost::filesystem::path (fname)
        );

    std::ifstream file (fname, std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
    boost::iostreams::filtering_istream in;
    in.push (boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor());
    in.push (file);

    std::string line;
    size_t bytes_read = 0;
    while (in)
    {
        std::getline (in, line);
        bytes_read += line.size ();
        // progress dlg with bytes_read / uncompressed size
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The information you are after is definitely there (uncompressed data size is recorded into the last 4 bytes of a gzip file, (see [GZIP spec](http://www.gzip.org/zlib/rfc-gzip.html)) but taking a look at the headers for the boost library (seen [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp)) it is not exposed anywhere.  The only place it seems to be even looked at is when doing checks to make sure there was no corruption in read_footer.
You could read the value yourself directly out of the file (just assemble the last 4 bytes into an int, being mindful of their ordering (see GZIP spec again)), or use a different library to do the unzipping.

Comment: It's easy enough to seek to the end of the file and read the size.  I guess I'll do that. Thanks.

Comment: Or, you could modify boost to add this information and submit a patch for it.  Then everybody benefits from the work.